# Youtube Data api reached the limit too fast beacuse of bots

Tags: php, curl, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

My youtube api key reaching the limit fast in few hours because alot of bots search  and its flooding my requests to the api, There is a way to avoid the bots but let them index the pages in search engines

MY CODE :

```
    function search ($keyword, $apikey, $maxResults) {      
    $googleApiUrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=' . urlencode($keyword) . '&maxResults=' . $maxResults . '&key=' . $apikey;

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $googleApiUrl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
    $data = json_decode($response);
    $value = json_decode(json_encode($data), true);
    return $value;
}
```

Any suggestions ? Thanks in advance

Comment: What does your api key have to do with bots?  Your api key is reaching its limit because you are making to many requests.  Make fewer requests.

Comment: @DaImTo Its searching videos website and the bots search by themselfs and I dont want them to search but I want them index my website to search engings

Comment: add a captcha. also, don't do a search if $keyword is empty.

Comment: I would urge you to implement some sort of caching. Doing caching the right way is not easy (it's usually not done in a few lines of code), but it's extremely effective in reducing API requests.